# Unable to login to Azure IoT Hub with cellular MQTT AT command

Tags: mqtt, azure-iot-hub, cellular-network

I'm using a u-Blox SARA-R422M8S cellular module trying to connect to Azure Iot Hub with the MQTT AT commands. The module supports MQTT 3.1.1. The login request fails with `Broker connection refused, not authorized`. Using the same credentials in the python example at [Microsoft Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support), the login succeeds and I can publish. I've uploaded the Baltimore root cert and activated the TLS for the socket, so this seems ok as well as I get another error code elsewise.

Anyone experienced similar?

PS, here are the AT commands used:

AT+USECPRF=0

AT+USECPRF=0,0,1

AT+USECPRF=0,3,"root_ca"

AT+UPSD=0,0,0

AT+UPSD=0,100,1

AT+UMQTT=11,1,0

AT+UMQTT=2,".azure-devices.net",8883

AT+UMQTT=4,"*myhub*.azure-devices.net/*mydev*/?api-version=2018-06-30","*mysas*""

Comment: Hate you tried setting the ClientID? (`AT+UMQTT=0,"mydev"`).

Comment: Thanks, this seems to solve the login problem. None of the documents/examples I've read so far has set the device id :)

Comment: Can you post the comment as answer to this and verify to help others?

Answer (score 0):

As per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#using-the-mqtt-protocol-directly-as-a-device):

> For the ClientId field, use the deviceId.

So you need to set the Client ID with something like:

`AT+UMQTT=0,"mydev"`